# Vertical text recognition in Android

Tags: android, ocr, text-recognition

We want to implement functionality for text recognition in Android. Please suggest best possible way.

Sample text will be like this(vertical text):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
Output should be "12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

hi use this below link if you can use 
https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr